# GCP Cloud Run error on deploying my Docker image to Google Container Registry / Cloud Run

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, docker-compose, dockerfile, google-cloud-run

i´m quite new to Docker and GCP and try to find a working way, to deploy my Laravel App on GCP.
I already set up CI and and selected "cloudbuild.yaml" as build configuration. I followed innumerable tutorials and read the Google Container Docs, so i created a "cloudbuild.yaml" which includes arguments to use my docker-composer.yaml, to create the stack of my app (app code, database, server).

**During the Google Cloud Build process i get:**

```
Step #0: Creating workspace_app_1 ... 
Step #0: Creating workspace_web_1 ... 
Step #0: Creating workspace_db_1  ... 
Step #0: Creating workspace_app_1 ... done
Step #0: Creating workspace_web_1 ... done
Step #0: Creating workspace_db_1  ... done
Finished Step #0
Starting Step #1
Step #1: Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
Step #1: unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat /workspace/Dockerfile: no such file or directory
Finished Step #1
ERROR
ERROR: build step 1 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
```

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: "3.8"
volumes:
  php-fpm-socket:
  db-store:
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./infra/docker/php/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - php-fpm-socket:/var/run/php-fpm
      - ./backend:/work/backend
    environment:
      - DB_CONNECTION=mysql
      - DB_HOST=db
      - DB_PORT=3306
      - DB_DATABASE=${DB_NAME:-laravel_local}
      - DB_USERNAME=${DB_USER:-phper}
      - DB_PASSWORD=${DB_PASS:-secret}

  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./infra/docker/nginx/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - ${WEB_PORT:-80}:80
    volumes:
      - php-fpm-socket:/var/run/php-fpm
      - ./backend:/work/backend

  db:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./infra/docker/mysql/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - ${DB_PORT:-3306}:3306
    volumes:
      - db-store:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${DB_NAME:-laravel_local}
      - MYSQL_USER=${DB_USER:-phper}
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${DB_PASS:-secret}
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${DB_PASS:-secret}
```

**cloudbuild.yaml**

```
    steps:
  # running docker-compose
  - name: 'docker/compose:1.28.4'
    args: ['up', '-d']
  # Build the container image
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args: ['build', '-t', 'gcr.io/MY_PROJECT_ID/laravel-docker-1', '.']
  # Push the container image to Container Registry
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args: ['push', 'gcr.io/MY_PROJECT_ID/laravel-docker-1']
  # Deploy container image to Cloud Run
  - name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk'
    entrypoint: gcloud
    args: ['run', 'deploy', 'laravel-docker-1', '--image', 'gcr.io/MY_PROJECT_ID/laravel-docker-1', '--region', 'europe-west3', '--platform', 'managed']
  
images:
- gcr.io/MY_PROJECT_ID/laravel-docker-1
```

What is wrong in this configuration?

Comment: you perform a docker build. Docker expect a docker file. Where is it? What is it content?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue to deploy a running Laravel 8 application to Google Cloud with the following Dockerfile. PS: Any optimization regarding the FROM and RUN steps are appreciated:

```
#
# PHP Dependencies
#
FROM composer:2.0 as vendor

WORKDIR /app

COPY database/ database/
COPY composer.json composer.json
COPY composer.lock composer.lock

RUN composer install \
    --no-interaction \
    --no-plugins \
    --no-scripts \
    --no-dev \
    --prefer-dist

COPY . .
RUN composer dump-autoload

#
# Frontend
#
FROM node:14.9 as frontend

WORKDIR /app

COPY artisan package.json webpack.mix.js package-lock.json ./

RUN npm audit fix
RUN npm cache clean --force
RUN npm cache verify

RUN npm install -f

COPY resources/js ./resources/js
COPY resources/sass ./resources/sass

RUN npm run development



#
# Application
#
FROM php:7.4-fpm

WORKDIR /app

# Install PHP dependencies
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y build-essential libxml2-dev libonig-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql opcache tokenizer xml ctype json bcmath pcntl

# Install Linux and Python dependencies
RUN apt-get install -y curl wget git file ruby-full locales vim

# Run definitions to make Brew work
RUN localedef -i en_US -f UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8
RUN useradd -m -s /bin/zsh linuxbrew && \
    usermod -aG sudo linuxbrew &&  \
    mkdir -p /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew && \
    chown -R linuxbrew: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew
USER linuxbrew
RUN /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"

USER root
#RUN chown -R $CONTAINER_USER: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew
ENV PATH "$PATH:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin"

#Install Chrome
RUN wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
RUN apt install -y ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb

# Install Python modules (dependencies) of scraper
RUN brew install python3
RUN pip3 install selenium
RUN pip3 install bs4
RUN pip3 install pandas

# Copy Frontend build
COPY --from=frontend app/node_modules/ ./node_modules/
COPY --from=frontend app/public/js/ ./public/js/
COPY --from=frontend app/public/css/ ./public/css/
COPY --from=frontend app/public/mix-manifest.json ./public/mix-manifest.json

# Copy Composer dependencies
COPY --from=vendor app/vendor/ ./vendor/
COPY . .
RUN cp /app/drivers/chromedriver /usr/local/bin
#COPY .env.prod ./.env
COPY .env.local-docker ./.env

# Copy the scripts to docker-entrypoint-initdb.d which will be executed on container startup
COPY ./docker/ /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
COPY ./docker/init_db.sql .

RUN php artisan config:cache
RUN php artisan route:cache

CMD php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8080

EXPOSE 8080
```

Comment: This is an interesting answer but the scripts that the Dockerfile reference are required to verify your answer. You are also installing a lot of packages with no notes on why.

Comment: don't run `php artisan serve` in production. use an reverse proxy.